# Prove to be hyperbolae $x^2 - y^2 = a$ and $xy = b$ intersect at right angle.

Tags: derivatives, proof-verification, conic-sections, implicit-differentiation

Prove to be hyperbolae
$x^2 - y^2 = a$   and $xy = b$ intersect at right angle.

My idea:
$$h_1:=x^2 - y^2 = a$$
$$h_2:=xy = b$$
By using implicit differentiation we can find $h_1'$ and $h_2'$.
$$x^2 - y^2 = a$$
$$2x-2yy'=0$$
$$y'=\frac{x}{y} \tag{1}$$
$$xy = b$$
$$y+xy'=0$$
$$y'=-\frac{y}{x} \tag{2} $$

This prove that $h_1$ and $h_2$ intersect at right angle for all $x$ and $y$, but $x$ any $y$ can't be equal to zero.
Is my work ok?

Answer (score 2):

Let $(X,Y)$ be the **intersection**, then the equations of the tangents of the conics are:

$$
\left \{
  \begin{eqnarray*}
    Xx-Yy &=& a \\
    \frac{Yx+Xy}{2} &=& b
  \end{eqnarray*}
\right.
$$

Their slopes are $\displaystyle \frac{X}{Y}$ and $\displaystyle -\frac{Y}{X}$ respectively.

Hence they are perpendicular.

Answer (score 0):

Note that slopes of (1), (2) (m1,m2) have a product  -1, a condition of orthogonality..it is done. Because in

$$ \tan \pi/2 = \infty = \frac{m1-m2}{1+ m1 \,m2} $$

denominator is zero

Answer (score 0):

Your solution looks good to me.

You can also do this using gradients instead of implicit differentiation: $$
\nabla h_1 \cdot \nabla h_2 = (2x,-2y)\cdot(y,x) = 0.
$$ The gradients are normal to the level curves, so since they are orthogonal, then so are the curves.