# How to solve the Initial value problem $\left\{y' = \frac{x}{y}, y(2) = 10\right\} $?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems, cauchy-problem

$$\left\{y' = \frac{x}{y},  y(2) = 10\right\} $$

I am asked what $y(1)$ is.
In order to solve this Cauchy's problem, this is what I've tried.

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x}{y} \rightarrow ydy = xdx$$
$$\int{ydy} = \int{xdx} \rightarrow \frac{y^2}{2} = \frac{x^2}{2}+c$$
$$y = x + \sqrt{2c}$$

Then I have that
$$y(2) = 10 \rightarrow 10 = 2 + \sqrt{2c} \rightarrow 8 = \sqrt{2c} \rightarrow c = 32$$

So $y(1)$ would be:
$$y(1) = 1 + 8 = 9$$

but, the answer is actually $y(1) = \sqrt{97}$.

This is demotivating. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should have $$y = \sqrt{x^2 + 2 c}$$

Comment: $\frac{y^2}{2}=\frac{x^2}{2}+c$ does not imply $y=x+\sqrt{2c}$.

Comment: You guys are right! It was a silly mistake.

$$y = \sqrt{x^2+2c}$$
$$10=\sqrt{4+2c} \rightarrow 100 = 4+2c \rightarrow c = 48$$
$$y(1) = \sqrt{96+1} = \sqrt{97}$$

Comment: The solutions of ordinary differential equation $y'=x/y$ are hyperbolas ; ordinary differential equation associated with orthogonal curves, $y'=-y/x$ has hyperbolas as solutions as well (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1725071)